# How can I create a dashboard across multiple Azure DevOps Projects?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop

For my work I've been assigned multiple Azure DevOps projects that I have been asked to create dashboards for. My boss is interested in a dashboard for each individual project (at that project level) and one master dashboard that consolidates all the information across projects. I've looked at the main Microsoft support link for this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/work-across-projects-faqs?view=azure-devops), as well as numerous other resources, and I am still having several issues. I'm trying to work around the following constraints:

1. We don't want to create another project and use the "Query Across Projects" feature, as we are trying to utilize the hierarchical structure of Azure DevOps projects.
2. We'd like to avoid OData Queries / PowerBI, as I've run into numerous issues with them. Specifically, the data I get from the query is in a very ugly format (almost entirely hashed strings and other unclean data).

I'm open to any and all suggestions and would really appreciate pointers to other resources - I've had a hard time finding people who are looking to do similar tasks or who are having similar problems, so any help is much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on it, I guess we have a dashboard very much coupled with project.
Program level dashboard as in project management. But there is concept of Portfolio management, check if that helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/portfolio-management?view=azure-devops

Comment: This is what I originally suggested to my boss, but she seems to want to keep the projects separate and not have one project with teams underneath it (although I agree that this would likely solve the problem). Is there anything similar that could be done with projects?

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-delivery-plans/3-what-is-delivery-plans

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a dashboard across multiple Azure DevOps Projects?

Starting from November 12 2020, MS announce a public preview for [Delivery Plans 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-178-update#features), which provide a first-class roadmap and timeline solution natively in Azure Boards. The initial preview will include these features:

- Bringing Delivery Plans into the core product, rather than requiring
  an extension to be installed.
- Enabling work items to span iteration boundaries.
- Enabling drag and drop borders to show when a work item starts and
  ends.
- Enabling stakeholders to view plans.

Use Delivery Plans to ensure your teams are aligned with your organizational goals. You can **view multiple backlogs and multiple teams across your whole account**. You can interact with the plan with simple drag-and-drop operations to update or modify the schedule, opening cards, expanding and collapsing teams, and more.

[image]

You could check the document [Review team Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Comment: This is very helpful and close to what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get the same dashboard elements (graphs from queries, burndown / burnup, etc.) into a delivery plan? Or another solution that allows us to do that?

Comment: @SpencerHylen, I am afraid not at this moment.

Comment: I'd like to accept this but it still hasn't solved the problem. I guess the current answer is that there is no solution, but that doesn't really help me at work. Are there no other alternatives via Power BI or other Microsoft tools? I know I mentioned the issues I've had above with Power BI and OData queries but am really willing to try anything.